# Error al graficar con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Tengo problemas al momento de graficar usando matlpotlib.

Abro un csv para extraer un conjunto de datos, determinando a dónde se irán los valores de X y Y, ya sea a One, Five o Seven basándome en el valor de la tercera columna.

El problema radica al momento de graficar, ya que se muestran los números completamente revueltos y no comprendo por qué, tengo entendido que la función

```
plt.plot(oneX, oneY, 'bo')
```

recibe en su primer argumento una lista con los valores de x y en el segundo argumento una lista con los valores de y, que es exactamente lo que le estoy pasando.

Agradecería mucho si alguien puede indicarme qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Anexo mi código y el dataset que estoy usando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
import math

class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color

points = []

with open('datasheet.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            #print(f'Column names are: {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            #print(f'\t ({row[0]}, {row[1]}) color: {row[2]}.')
            points.append(Point(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
            line_count += 1
    #print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')

oneX = []
oneY = []
fiveX = []
fiveY = []
sevenX = []
sevenY = []

for i in range(len(points)):
    #print(f'{points[i].x} {points[i].y} {points[i].color}')
    if points[i].color == '1':
        oneX.append(points[i].x)
        oneY.append(points[i].y)
    elif points[i].color == '5':
        fiveX.append(points[i].x)
        fiveY.append(points[i].y)
    elif points[i].color == '7':
        sevenX.append(points[i].x)
        sevenY.append(points[i].y)

print(oneX)
print(oneY)
print(fiveX)
print(fiveY)
print(sevenX)
print(sevenY)


plt.plot(oneX, oneY, 'bo')
plt.plot(fiveX, fiveY, 'go')
plt.plot(sevenX, sevenY, 'ro')
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.xlabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

Y el archivo que abro con nombre datasheet.txt es el siguiente

```
x,y,number
459,259,1
738,435,1
473,315,1
1094,605,1
610,365,1
806,488,1
768,467,1
539,302,1
472,288,1
666,410,1
519,295,1
1093,640,1
757,454,1
493,319,1
830,523,1
630,420,1
1300,732,5
1089,672,5
1095,665,5
1097,686,5
1372,891,5
1214,782,5
1253,753,5
1318,814,5
1547,972,5
1383,883,5
1509,912,5
1441,914,5
1365,803,5
1316,785,5
1440,832,5
1353,841,5
1098,721,7
825,610,7
769,562,7
416,926,7
1089,761,7
1505,981,7
1531,991,7
1185,791,7
1137,806,7
1463,936,7
1307,854,7 
1072,730,7
1394,903,7
1252,836,7
1141,757,7
1448,985,7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no conviertes las coordenadas `x` e `y` a entero, al ser cadenas Matplotlib los grafica como si fueran datos categóricos sin más:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color


with open('datasheet.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)  # Descartamos primera línea
    points = [Point(int(x), int(y), color) for x, y, color in csv_reader]

one_x = []
one_y = []
five_x = []
five_y = []
seven_x = []
seven_y = []

for point in points:
    if point.color == '1':
        one_x.append(point.x)
        one_y.append(point.y)
    elif point.color == '5':
        five_x.append(point.x)
        five_y.append(point.y)
    elif point.color == '7':
        seven_x.append(point.x)
        seven_y.append(point.y)

print(one_x)
print(one_y)
print(five_x)
print(five_y)
print(seven_x)
print(seven_y)


plt.plot(one_x, one_y, 'bo')
plt.plot(five_x, five_y, 'go')
plt.plot(seven_x, seven_y, 'ro')
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.xlabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un descuido que me costó mucho tiempo. Gracias!